# Solidity error while transfering value from one address to another

Tags: mapping, solidity, transfer

I am developing a smart contract to make donations. I have a mapping where all the proyects avalaible are stored indetified with an ID. I am writing the function to donate, but I get this error in remix:

```
transact to Donacion.donate errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

This would be my function:

```
    function donate(uint _id, uint amount) public payable {

        require(_id > 0 && _id <= proyectID); //proyectID is a global variable which increases while the people upload their proyects

        //Identify the proyect we want to donate
        Proyecto memory _proyect = proyects[_id];

        //If the wanted donation have not been reached we can donate
        require(_proyect.donation < _proyecto.wantedDonation);

        //Identify the author of the proyect who we want to donate
        address payable _author = _proyecto.author;

        //Donate
        _author.transfer(amount);

        //Increase the received donation of this proyect
        _proyecto.donation = _proyecto.donation + amount;

        //Return the proyect to the mapping
        proyects[_id] = _proyect;

    }
```

These are the mapping and the struct of the proyects:

```
mapping(uint => Proyect) public proyects;

struct Proyect{
        uint id; 
        string hash; 
        string name;
        address payable author;
        uint donation;
        uint wantedDonation
    }
```

I tried to debug it in remix and I think that the error is in the line

```
_author.transfer(amount);
```

I'm not sure that this is the error though. I also tried

```
aaddress(_author).transfer(amount);
```

but I got the same error.

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my javaScript file. If you try in remix you only have to specify the value of the transaction in the interface of remix, but I'm getting the value to donate from a form of my interface.

So, at the end I only had to specify the transaction value using web3.

```
async function donate(_id) {
  const contractInstance = await init();
  let ac = await getAccount();
    let amount = document.getElementById("donationAmount").value;
    await contractInstance.methods.donate(_id,amount).send({from: ac,value: web3.utils.toWei(amount,"ether")});
}
```